# Looking for a Java solution for creating an XML document from a list of value/XPath pairs

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have two columns in a spreadsheet.

One column is an XPath expression used to get a value from an existing XML document. 
The other column is an XPath expression from which I need to create my XSLT/output XML document.  The value grabbed from the first column will be the value placed in the second column's element.

So for example if the second column has the XPath /A/B/C, I would create

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C><xsl:value-of select = "corresponding value from 1st column"/></C>
  </B>
</A>
```

If the next XPath is /A/B/D, I would add

```
<D><xsl:value-of select = "corresponding value from 1st column"/></D>
```

as a sibling of C.

I'm expected to create this output XML/XSLT structure by hand.  However there are thousands of lines.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to do this programmatically in Java.  I've never mixed Java/XML/XPath so maybe there are libraries that can help with this?
If it's an enormous undertaking I won't be able to justify it as opposed to just doing it by hand.  If I can write something that gets me most of the way there I'd be happy. 
Is this a pipe dream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, most Java XML libraries support retrieving DOM nodes via XPath quite painlessly.  Often they use [Jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/) as their backend, so make sure you have the Jaxen JAR in your class path.  See XPath support in [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/xpath/XPathFactory.html), [DOM4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669625/using-xpath-in-dom4j), and [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/tutorial.xhtml#d0e1828).

Comment: In fact most of these operations can be done using xslt classes within the JDK itslef. Check this example http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0625.html However you can also go with Jaxen or Xalan as well as mentioned by Eric

Comment: As a note: your link to JDOM API docs refers to old version 1.1.3. While the current is [JDOM 2.0.4 API](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: Thank you!  The perils of using Google as a reference.  I'll update the link in the answer.